# Who is krishnamma in the legend of hathiram baba?

Tags: vishnu, bhakti, venkateshwara, tirupati, telugu

In a Telugu movie, **Om Namo Venkateshaya** , which is based on the story of hathiram ji, it was depicted that there was also a devotee named **krishnamma**.

Who is she? Was she real? Or just depicted for the sake of movie?

Comment: Movie questions should be directed to the screenwriters of the movie. Movie questions are not about the Hindu religion.

Comment: She is not a real character. You can understand it from [here](https://youtu.be/f_PzwonIe0s?t=3215) and [here](https://youtu.be/V4FtR8ae7eI?t=770).

Comment: @hanugm Sir can you please translate to what the team told at those two points? I don't understand Telugu.

Comment: @Chamundadas The director of the movie is saying that we created the character of Krishnamma as a person in the lineage of maths (say vengamamba, godha) etc., that exists in tirumala.

Comment: @hanugm Thanks alot sir. Obliged

Comment: @hanugm thank u. Btw, what your name mean? (If u don't mind)

Comment: @Learner pastime name.